# Azure AD B2C - Sign Up via Graph API and Sign In Afterwards

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I'm designing a registration page for our website application.
Since the registration page is fairly complex in terms of page design, We've decided to not use an Azure B2C user flow, but design our own page and send a registration request to our API which would use the Graph API to register the user (among other things).

The problem is that we want to do an automatic sign-in right after registration (i.e. we don't want to prompt a login page after the user has registered, we want to redirect him directly to our website).

I can use the ROPC flow to issue a refresh token for the web app. The problem is that the web app uses the MSAL.js library today, which only supports the implicit flow, so we can't use a refresh token unless we redesign the auth section of the web app, which is something that I want to avoid.

Is there anything I can do to support automatic sign-in after registration without using refresh tokens?

Comment: Through custom policies it could be possible with id_token_hint etc., but it's quite hard to setup.

Comment: So you suggest creating a custom policy that reads and verifies the `id_token_hint`, reads from AD and redirects back to my application without any input from the user?

Comment: Yeah, that should in theory work

Comment: @user10962730 Any update for this issue?

Comment: @TonyJu I couldn't think of any other solutions other than what juunas suggested, but I would like to avoid custom policies if possible, so I'm waiting for other answers.

Comment: Is there any update on this? I have a similar requirement, in fact I could even redirect the user for the actual login, but I would like to use B2C to verify phone number and email for me, during the registration api call. (1) create account (2) otp email, (3) otp phone.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use id_token_hint in this case. Because the replication delay you will encounter when you do a sign in (via b2c) after a sign up (via api), and to get a proper set of tokens into the msal instance. The id_token_hint parameter should be generated by the API who creates the account, and send back to the App. The App should initialize msal with "extraQueryParamaters: id_token_hint=tokenValueFromAPI. That will redirect the user to your id token hint B2C custom policy journey, and auto sign in the user.

[Here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/id-token-builder) is how you build an id_token_hint.
[Here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/policy/SignUpInvitation.xml#L161) Is a B2C policy that can extract an id_token_hint

The key is, in the RelyingParty section you need
1. [Claims to map into the id token hint read operation](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/policy/SignUpInvitation.xml#L200)
2. [The id token hint extraction technical profile](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/policy/SignUpInvitation.xml#L134)
3. [The first step in your journey to call the id token hint extraction technical profile](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/invite/policy/SignUpInvitation.xml#L162)
4. Step 2 in your journey can read any additional data from the directory, or just issue a token based off the input from the id_token_hint claim set.